# Data not display in textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, textarea

I am binding the DATA in mvc via below code:

```
@model DocumentManagementSystem.Models.DocumentFileName
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table style="margin-top:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.Data, new { ViewBag.DocumentData })
}
```

The DATA bind is from Viewbag. I give this value to `textarea`. It shows using F12 in source, but it does not show in the UI part. I've attached screenshot for that:

[image: shows in code but not in ui]

I've highlighted the value which was not seen in same `textarea`.

Below is my controller code through which i post the data into Viewbag:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                object filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document/"), file.FileName);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass AC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = true;
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                var retString = "";
                try
                {
                    doc = AC.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
                    retString = doc.Content.Text;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    retString = ex.ToString();
                }
                ViewBag.DocumentData = new MvcHtmlString(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(retString.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.result = "Document Not Support";
            }
            return View("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that with textareafor as far as I'm aware, because it is bound to the value of `Model.Data`.

Could you not declare your `Model.Data` to = `ViewBag.DocumentData` just before you use textareafor?

EDIT: E.g:

```
@model DocumentManagementSystem.Models.DocumentFileName
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Model.Data = ViewBag.DocumentData;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 

    @Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.Data)
}
```

Comment: I am not getting you, please explain it.

Comment: You have defined a Model at the top of your razor file. `DocumentManagementSystem.Models.DocumentFileName`.

Your TextAreaFor is bound to the "Data" property of that Model.

If you set `Model.Data = ViewBag.DocumentData` before you use TextAreaFor, then the text area produced will have the value of whatever you have set `ViewBag.DocumentData` to be.

Comment: where do i set 'Model.Data = ViewBag.DocumentData'

Comment: I am facing 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error now

Comment: Can you post the controller action code which displays this view please. So I can see if you are creating and passing a model to it correctly.

Comment: i have edit my code and put controller code, please refer it

Comment: If i Bind data using @Html.TextBox("fullname", (HtmlString)ViewBag.DocumentData) then it will bind correctly.